# swift how to convert string to date fraction seconds

Tags: string, swift, date

I have a string want to convert to date, but below code,

that str

print out show `Optional(2016-04-25 17:00:16 +0000)`

I want to know how to show exact what it is like  `Optional(2016-04-26T03:00:16.047)`

```
var str = "2016-04-26T03:00:16.047"


    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"//this your string date format
   dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)

    print(date)   //Optional(2016-04-25 17:00:16 +0000)
```

Comment: Your date is ok just use NSDateFormatter stringFromDate and dont change timezone

Comment: if delete that line,  dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")  date is not right, it change to Optional(2016-04-25 17:00:16 +0000)   which is not the right date

Comment: just want to know how to show 047 out

Comment: Dont change timezone just use stringFromDate to show your localtime